# Can't add argument to custom command

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel 5.1. in a debian bash shell. I created a custom console command called survey:complete. I've been using it for a while, and now I want to add an optional argument for the number of surveys to generate.

However, I've followed the documentation, but I haven't been able to successfully add my argument. I changed the signature likewise:

```
protected $signature = 'survey:complete {--number=}';
```

And tried to reference the argument

```
public function handle() { 
    for( $i = 0; $i < $this->argument('number'); $i++ ) {
```

But I get this error:

```
$> php artisan survey:complete --number=1
[InvalidArgumentException]
The "number" argument does not exist.
```

I print_r()'d the arguments array, and I get this:

```
$ php artisan survey:complete --number=1
Array(
    [command] => survey:complete
)
[InvalidArgumentException]
The "number" argument does not exist.
```

How do I add my argument to my command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I needed to use `option()`, not `argument()`.

```
$number = $this->option('number');
```

Comment: var_dump($this->options()) to see them all.

Comment: It says right in the docs that argument is what you need, but it doesn't work at all. This makes no sense. Thanks for the tip, "option" worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me instead:

```
   protected $signature = 'mycommand {limit=1000}'
   // call: php artisan mycommand 100
```

I retrieve the value with:

```
public function handle() {    
    // ...
    $limit = $this->arguments('limit')['limit']
    // ...
}
```